# git revert - nothing seems to work

Tags: git

I needed to revert a few commits back. I tried a few things and then I noticed I was several commits behind `master`. not exactly sure what I did, but things got pretty messed up. This is just some code that I'm fooling around with luckily, so I want to just get back to a specific commit and continue on my way, even if it destroys/erases subsequent commits.

I tried:

`git revert <commit>`

`git reset --hard master github/master`

`git rebase -i HEAD~11`

`git reset --hard <commit>`

Comment: And your question is?  `git reset --hard <commit>` will do what you what...unless what you want is different than 'get back to a specific commit'.  In what way did that command not do what you want?

Comment: when I try to `push` changes made after I `reset --hard`, I get this error: `hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.` Hiw can I resolve this?

Comment: Try `git pull`, as the hint says.

Comment: but that takes me back to my last pushed commit.

Comment: and if i do: `git pull 6a53e59` I get an error
`fatal: '6a53e59' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: I think you are looking for: `git pull && git cherry-pick 6a53a59 && git push`,   which will apply the changes that were made in 6a53a59.

Comment: This msut be where the issue lies. Thats works for the commit prior to 6a53a59, but when I do it 6a53a59 I get `rror: could not apply 6a53e59... fixed bug in application.rb, capitalized module name
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'` and I can't seem to resolve these conflicts. I've tried adding, commiting and pushing, then trying again, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81922/discussion-between-william-pursell-and-dixon11111).